# Android Webview : Not allowed to load resource error library project

Tags: android, webview

My Application has custom webviews loading html (react based webpack build) from local assets folder. When I tried to load the webview , I see the error 
"Not allowed to load local resource : file:///android_asset/index.html/#/initialize?..."

Please note : the route ("index.html/#/..") added along with the html. If I load the html only, it works fine.

My application has permission to read and write from storage.

I cannot use loadDataWithBaseURL because the 2nd parameter expects a html data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - it was a simple issue.
 When using react route - the URL should be :

file:///android_asset/index.html#/initialize?...

and not file:///android_asset/index.html/#/initialize?...

Notice the extra '/' after the .html